# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]

Tags: javascript, express, post, methods

I am making a simple Express app and I get this error when I try to route a POST method:

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object String]
```

I have split my app.js into multiple routes, here are the relevant files:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var authRouter = require('./src/routes/authRoutes')();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/Auth', authRouter);
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/src/views');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //Serve react index page
  res.sendFile('/index.html', {root: __dirname + '/src/views/'});
});
app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

**authRoutes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var authRouter = express.Router();

var router = () => {
  authRouter.route('/signIn')
      .post('/', (req, res) => {
          console.log('hello POST');
      });
  return authRouter;
}

module.exports = router;
```

**index.html (snippet)**

```
  <div class="row" style="max-width: 776px">
    <form action="/Auth/signIn" method="post" class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
          <input id="icon_telephone" type="password" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_telephone">Password</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**File Tree**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXkCw.png)

I have looked up this issue, but the solutions I see don't seem to address my specific problem.  Thank you!

Comment: The error says that the `post` function got a string but it wants a function. The only call to `post` that I see in your code is in the **authRoutes.js** file. Sure enough, you're passing a string first. Try removing that first argument to `post` and just pass the callback function.

Comment: It worked, thank you!  I was under the impression that `post` always needed two arguments.